# How to count number of the textbox within a cell in a dynamically generated HTML Table using a JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I want to find how many fields are there of type 'text' within the cell no. 3 of every each and every row.I want to save this in an array and want to pass it to my aspx.cs page in Asp.NET C#. I am able to get the number of text box within a page but i want them to count as per the raw and cell number.

I am generating this table dynamically.[I want to get the number of text boxes within cell for each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeIcA.png)

Scenario : I am having a scenario in which I want to generate a test report for a candidate. user will enter report name and when he clicks on the plus button, it will generate a dynamic row (that contains two text boxes) for the subject information. Within the dynamically generated raw one more button is there to generate the sub category of the subject. All the subject and sub categories i wan to insert in a same table but, subject id will be the parent id of the sub-subjects. I want them to retrieve in a parent-child form. please have a look on the screen shot attached.

```html
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">

        .TemplateTable

        {

            width: 80%;

            margin-left: 3%;

            border: 2px solid #a7a8a7;

            margin-top: 30px;

            padding-left: 35px;

            font-size: 15px;

            font-style: initial;

            font-weight: bold;

            color: #a7a8a7;

            padding-top: 3px;

            padding-bottom: 3px;

        }

        .TemplateTable tr td div

        {

            float: left;

            padding-right: 10px;

            font-size: 16px;
            height: 22px;
        }

        .TemplateTable tr td div a

        {

            color: Blue;

        }

        .custom-tablePopup

        {

            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

            font-size: 13px;

            margin: 10px 0 0 0;

            padding: 0;

            border-right: 1px solid #bebebe;

            border-top: 1px solid #bebebe;

            border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe;

        }

        .custom-tablePopup th

        {

            background: #ff5c00 !important;

            text-align: left;

            border-left: 1px solid #bebebe;

            border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe;

            padding: 5px 8px;

            color: #fff;

        }

        .custom-tablePopup td

        {

            border-left: 1px solid #bebebe;

            padding: 4px 8px;

        }

        .custom-tablePopup tr:nth-child(even)

        {

            background: #f8f8f8;

        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var count = "1";

        function addRow(in_tbl_name) {

            var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];

            // create row

            var row = document.createElement("TR");

            // create table cell 2

            var td1 = document.createElement("TD")

            var strHtml2 = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"SName\" size=\"20\" maxlength=\"30\" />";

            td1.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g, count);

            // create table cell 3

            var td2 = document.createElement("TD")

            var strHtml3 = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"SScore\" size=\"10\" />";

            td2.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g, count);

            // create table cell 4

            var td3 = document.createElement("TD")

            var strHtml4 = "<img src=\"../Images/cancel.jpg\" onclick=\"delRow()\" style=\"width: 22px; cursor:pointer;\" />";

            td3.innerHTML = strHtml4.replace(/!count!/g, count);

              // create table cell 4

            var td4 = document.createElement("TD")

            var strHtml5 = "<img src=\"../Images/Plus.jpg\" onclick=\"AddSubRow()\" style=\"width: 22px; cursor:pointer;\" />";

            td4.innerHTML = strHtml5.replace(/!count!/g, count);

            // append data to row

            row.appendChild(td1);

            row.appendChild(td2);

            row.appendChild(td3);

             row.appendChild(td4);

            count = parseInt(count) + 1;

            // add to count variable

            // append row to table

            tbody.appendChild(row);

        }

        function delRow() {

            var current = window.event.srcElement;

            //here we will delete the line

            while ((current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName != "TR");

            current.parentElement.removeChild(current);

        }

        function AddSubRow() {

            var current = window.event.srcElement;

            var row1 = document.createElement("TR");

            // create table cell 1

            var td1 = document.createElement("TD")

            var strHtml2 = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"SubjectName\" size=\"20\" />";

           td1.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g, count);

            // create table cell 2

            var td2 = document.createElement("TD")

            var strHtml3 = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"SubjectScore\" size=\"10\" />";

            td2.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g, count);

            // create table cell 2

            var td3 = document.createElement("TD")

            var strHtml4 = "<img src=\"../Images/cancel.jpg\" onclick=\"delRow()\" style=\"width: 22px; cursor:pointer;\" />";

            td3.innerHTML = strHtml4.replace(/!count!/g, count);

               row1.appendChild(td1);
               row1.appendChild(td2);
               row1.appendChild(td3);
            //here we will delete the line

            //while ((current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName != "TR");

            current.parentElement.appendChild(row1); 

        }

        function Calculate() {

           // var oTable = document.getElementById('tblPets');
           
            var marks = [];
            var table = document.getElementById("tblPets");
            var column_count = table.rows[1].cells.length;
            var rowLength = table.rows.length;
            alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').length);

    }
   

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">

    <div id="dvReport" runat="server">

        <table class="TemplateTable" runat="server" >

            <tr>

                <td>
                    Report Name  <asp:TextBox ID="txtreportName" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td style="float: right;">

                    <div>

                        <img id="Img1" src="~/Images/Plus.jpg" width="20" runat="server" /></div>

                    <div>

                        <a title="Add Subject" style="cursor: pointer;font-family:Arial;color:navy" onclick="addRow('tblPets')">Add Subject</a>

                    </div>

                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>

    <div style="margin-left: 3%;" id="dvSubject" runat="server">

        <table id="tblPets" class="custom-tablePopup" runat="server">

            <tr>

                <th>Subject Name</th>

                <th>Subject Score</th>

                <th></th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td><input type="text" name="SName" size="20" /></td>

                <td><input type="text" name="SScore" size="10" /></td>

                <td><img src="../Images/Delete.png" onclick="delRow()" style="width: 22px; cursor: pointer;" /></td>

                <td><img src="../Images/Plus.jpg" onclick="AddSubRow()" style="width: 22px; cursor: pointer;" /></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="Calculate()"  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDisplay" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

    </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why do you generate the textboxes dynamically? Are you interested only in the number or also in the content of the textboxes later on?  It would be very helpful if you'd explain the context and add a small sample of your code.

Comment: I mean, it is really simple but we need to know the html structure, and would also be useful to show what you've attempted/done so far.

Comment: I am having a scenario in which I want to generate a test report for a candidate. so user will enter report name and when he clicks on the plus button, it will generate a dynamic row (that contains two text boxes) for the subject information. Within the dynamically generated raw one more button is there to generate the sub category of the subject. All the subject and sub categories i wan to insert in a same table but, subject id will be the parent id of the sub-subjects. I want them to retrieve in a parent-child form. please have a look on the screen shot attached.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a specific class to the wanted elements, use javascript QuerySelector 
`document.querySelectorAll('.specific-class').length;`

Comment: I want to count text box for each and every cell number. I don't want to count within a document.